# MySQL, merging 2 or more tables before execute SELECT DISTINCT query?

Tags: mysql, distinct

I want to calculate how many unique logins from 2 (or probably more tables).

I tried this:

```
SELECT count(distinct(l1.user_id)) 
FROM `log_1` l1 
LEFT JOIN `log_2` l2 
ON l1.userid = l2.userid;
```

But it gives me result of l1. If I didn't put l1 on li.userid (distinct), it said "ambiguous".

How do I combine the table, and then select unique login of the combined table?

EDIT:

Tested: I test the count(distinct(l1.userid)) and count(distinct(l2.userid)). It gives me different result

Comment: Can you define what you mean by "combine the table"? Do you want users that appear in either table? Users that appear in both tables? Something else?

Comment: @Mark Byers: I think it would be more accurate, if the users appear on both tables right? It takes really long to combines 4 tables, more than 2 minutes, and I am still waiting now. (Using my code above, change the LEFT JOIN to INNER JOIN)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using `LEFT JOIN` then you will get at least one row in the combined result for each row in l1, so the join is entirely unnecessary if you just want a distinct count.  This would give you the same result as your query:

```
SELECT count(distinct(l1.user_id)) 
FROM `log_1` l1
```

Perhaps you want an `INNER JOIN` or `UNION` instead? A `UNION` will count a user if they appear in either table. An `INNER JOIN` will count them only if they appear in both tables. Here's an example of the `UNION`:

```
SELECT count(*) FROM (
    SELECT distinct(user_id) FROM `log_1`
    UNION
    SELECT distinct(user_id) FROM `log_2`
) T1
```